# Problems with a constraint in Julia JuMP

Tags: constraints, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, julia-jump

I'm having troubles with the following constraint in JuMP

```
@constraint(m, rBalance[h in H, k in P, m in M], sum(X[i,h,k,m] for i in SO) == (sum(X[h,h,k,r] for r in M if r!=m) + sum(X[h,j,k,m] for j in SD if j!= h)).
```

I got the following error msg

"No method matching add_Contraint(::String, ::ScalarConstraint{GenericAffExpr{Float64,VariableRef},MathOptInterface.EqualTo{Float64}},::String)" (see attached screenshot for more details)

[image: error msg]

Any thoughts?

Cheers
Guillermo

Comment: In the future please include your error message as text in your question. It makes it easier for others to quickly see what is wrong and how to help you.

Comment: Please enter error messages as text, not screenshots. A minimum working example demonstrating the issue would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Both your model and your index are named `m`. This is a common error; it's why we removed all instances of `m = Model()` from the examples that we provide.